# how to convert a string to an integer in java

Tags: java, android

i get an error when try to convert a string to an integer

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
  String rate= "3.7";
  int age=20;
  boolean istrue=true;
  double salary=60.4;

  //convert to String
  String Newsalary=String.valueOf(salary);
  String Newage=String.valueOf(age);
  String Newistrue=String.valueOf(istrue);
  //convert to Integer
 int Newrate= Integer.parseInt(rate);//here is the probleme
  int NewsalaryInt=(int) salary; 
  //convert to double
  double NewrateDouble=Double.parseDouble(rate);
  double NewageDouble=(double) age;


  }
  }
```

the problem is when i convert rate varaible which is String to an integer

Comment: the value stored inside string rate is "3.7". You cannot convert it to integer as integers cannot have decimal values. However, you can store decimal values to a Double using `Double.parseDouble(rate);`

Answer (score 1):

You'll get `java.lang.NumberFormatException` because you are trying to parse a double value into Integer value; so instead you need to either make your `rate` String holds an integer value like `String rate= "3";` 
or change below line

```
int Newrate= Integer.parseInt(rate);//here is the probleme
```

into

```
double Newrate= Double.parseDouble(rate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that rate is essentially a double so Integer.parseInt can't parse it. I'd guess it see's the decimal value and doesn't know what to do. Instead use Double.parseDouble(rate) and then cast it as an int.